# What is the head verb in the sentence "The tree will be tall"?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis, exceptions

a complete one but without a verb, specifically it IS a prediction, but what branch of structure does it come under?(declarative,imperative etc.)[image]

Comment: I'm probably not versed enough in grammar to answer your question, but can you clarify what you mean by "without a verb"? In your example, "will" is a verb. Or do you think it's an auxillary or something else that doesn't count in some way?

Comment: It's a schoolbook sentence, that's what it is. It's not a sentence anyone would say except under unusual conditions. It's made up by a schoolteacher for students to stew about. It's declarative, if that matters, because it isn't a question or an order. But this sentence has a subject noun phrase, two verbs, both auxiliary verbs, and a predicate adjective.

Comment: Do you have the list of sentence structures that you can share with us? How do you classify them? Declarative/Imperative/Interrogative/exclamatory? It is definitely declarative as it doesn't belong to others.

Comment: @JohnLawler I mean, the semantics are contrived, but the structure isn't: "Going surfing? Bring a wetsuit, the water will be cold".

Comment: It'd be contracted in speech, so the sentence with "will" is strictly for formal writing, which means it's from a textbook (probably ESL, since there are so many more), and flogging the (usually non-native speaker) author's ideas about what's important to learn and know about English grammar. This is a perfect example of a question that shouldn't be here.

Comment: The sentence has two verbs: *will* and *be*.

Comment: @JohnLawler I don't think it's true that it would always be contracted. I just recited the example I gave you above to myself, and it sounded perfectly natural.

Comment: @DanBron there's nothing wrong with *the water will be cold*, but I think the point is that you wrote it  (even if not in a formal context) rather than said it. Most native speakers contract future will to *'ll* in everyday speech. On the other hand, a number of speakers might avoid *water'll* because they find it difficult to pronounce and/or that it sounds weird.

Comment: @AlanCarmack I understood that, yes, but I was saying I tested it by, after having written it, saying aloud to myself, and it sounded fine and natural. Not artificial or stilted at all.  Also, to OP: what's with the picture? What are you trying to use it to tell us?

Comment: Hi @DanBron Agee, the sentence sounds fine. But that is not the same thing as saying it represents how native speakers actually talk. Recitation is not conversation.

Comment: @AlanCarmack I am a native speaker. Since I'd have to wait til someone actually said it to me to determine, in a non-biased way, whether it sounds weird at all, the best I can do is recitation + testing against my own natively-tuned ear.

Comment: @DanBron yeah, I know. Same for me. However, linguistic research turns up a lot of interesting things when it examines the actual evidence: what people actually say,  not what we think they/we  say. This has been true for me at least.  Cheers!

Comment: Of course the same applies to *the water'll be fine*. I might not like that in 'recitation', but I wouldn't be surprised if that's what I say in authentic, unforced, everyday conversation. @DanBron

Comment: @AlanCarmack I'm pretty sure I'd be OK saying *water'll*, as in if I said it or heard it said I wouldn't blink, but I'm not sure which of *water'll* or *water will* would actually come out of my mouth in extemporaneous speech.

Comment: @DanBron I was showing everyone, where I saw the sentence.

Comment: @AlanCarmack Will and be don't satisfy a complete sentence's need of a head verb.

Comment: @Gusto *Will* is the head verb. It is a [modal auxiliary](https://www.tesol-direct.com/tesol-resources/english-grammar-guide/modal-auxiliary-verbs/). It has only this form for the nonpast. It's past form is *would*. Modal auxiliaries are followed by the plain form of another verb, here it is *be*.

Comment: According to CGEL, a verb phrase requires a head verb. A head verb can only be used in a primary form, not a secondary form. The modal auxiliary *will* has no secondary form. It has only this primary form for the non-past (and the form *would* for the past tense) and it serves as the head of the verb phrase *will be*. Modal auxiliaries take the plain form (bare infinitive) of a verb as a complement; that is why it is *be* and not *to be*. CGEL = *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (2002) and there is a condensed version called *A Student’s Introduction to English Grammar* (2005)

Comment: @AlanCarmack so ok , can I definitely say that the sentence is in future tense, since the verb is in future tense?

Comment: English does not have a future tense, only different constructions that can refer to future time.  See [my comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/363125/what-is-the-head-verb-in-the-sentence-the-tree-will-be-tall?noredirect=1#comment845673_363156)

Comment: So how should I classify this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

"The tree will be tall" is no different from "The tree is tall", other than the future tense of "to be" is used instead of the the present tense.  Both are normal sentences with subject and predicate.

Comment: Grrr. *will be* is not the "future tense". It is the use of the modal will to refer to future time, and as such it is only one of 12+ ways to refer to future time. it's arbitrary to call *will be* the "future tense". One could  just as poorly pick another way to refer to future time and call it the future tense, such as *be going to be*.